# How to render images from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game kinda like Terraria (a blocky game).
I have already done the world generation, but I can't get it rendering properly.
The world is made out of columns and there are blocks in them.

Here's how a little part of the world looks in the program:

```js
[
    [ //column
        { //one block
            x: 1,
            y: 50,
            block: "dirt"
        }
    ] //column end
]
```

I tried rendering by clearing the div, then appending every single block that can be seen, but it's very slow.
If you want to see, go to [this link](http://termania.epizy.com)

And I don't really know that much about canvases, so if that's the only way, I have to learn it...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want to have a bit more blocks than one, I would highly suggest to take a look into canvas or even some libraries like pixi.js or something similar. DOM operations are quite slow

Comment: If you want to build a game in JS, I recommend using something like phaser.js. It uses the canvas (very fast), and has a ton of other tools built in (sprite sheet support, physics, object interaction, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);

Comment: Please add some explanation and/or context for your answer. Also, see: [Answer].

Comment: Ok, I got it working. And it's very fast!